# Not all Images are loading in my View when using URI as source

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, observablecollection, bindinglist

I am using Xamarin.Forms, using MVVM. When I was building the View, I used images embedded in the App, using ImageSource.FromResource, and everything was fine, all of my images loaded correctly in the view. When I changed the source to use a URI from my local webserver, only the bottom 3 images load on the view.

I have verified that all of the images exist on the server, and that the URI sent to the image source is correct.

I am not sure why only 3 images get loaded and the rest are blank.

Here is my code:

ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<KnownBird> _knownBirds { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<KnownBird> KnownBirds
{
    get
    {
        return _knownBirds;
    }
    set
    {
        _knownBirds = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("KnownBirds");
    }
}

public KnownBirdsViewModel()
{
    Title = "Known Birds";
    KnownBirds = new ObservableCollection<KnownBird>();
    LoadKnownBirdsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadBirdsCommand());
}

async Task ExecuteLoadBirdsCommand()
{
    if (IsBusy)
        return;

    IsBusy = true;

    try
    {
        KnownBirds.Clear();
        var _birds = await BirdService.GetKnownBirdsAsync();

        foreach (var tmpBird in _birds)
        {
            KnownBird tmpKB = new KnownBird();
            tmpKB.BirdID = tmpBird.BirdID;
            tmpKB.Name = tmpBird.Name;
            tmpKB.examplePicture = tmpBird.examplePicture;

            //Change this to URL when setting this from the REST API and not the local data.
            //tmpKB.BirdImage = ImageSource.FromResource("BirdWatcherMobileApp.SampleData.images." + tmpBird.examplePicture);

            tmpKB.BirdImage = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri("http://" + Settings.ServerAddress + "/images/bird_examples/" + tmpBird.examplePicture));

            KnownBirds.Add(tmpKB);
        }
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<flv:FlowListView
    FlowColumnCount="3"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    FlowItemsSource="{Binding KnownBirds, Mode=OneWay}" 
    FlowItemTapped="FlowListView_FlowItemTapped"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" 
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}" 
    RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadKnownBirdsCommand}">
        <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10" HeightRequest="125">
                    <Image Source="{Binding BirdImage, Mode=OneWay}" HeightRequest="100" />
                    <Label 
                        Text="{Binding Name}"
                        FontSize="16"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
</flv:FlowListView>
```

Right now I am thinking that loading the images from a webserver is taking time, and once the images are loaded into the Collection, and once the binding occurs the ListView never updates the binding and the images are not loaded.

I've read that when using an ObservableCollection, the OnPropertyChanged event is only fired when items are added or removed from the collection, and NOT when data inside an item is updated.

I have that a BindingList collection will raise an OnPropertyChanged event when data inside an item in the list is updated. I've tried to swap out the ObservableCollection with a BindingList, but then noting is loaded into the view.

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Are my suspicions correct? Any help or information here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use [FFImageLoading's](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading#ffimageloading---fast--furious-image-loading) CachedImage for this.

It is a library that is vastly accepted by the community and is great with caching and has memory handling options as well.

You can check their [Git wiki](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki) to understand the library in depth.

Download it form [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.FFImageLoading/)

Call `CachedImageRenderer.Init()` on each platform. Let’s put it on `MainActivity.cs` of our Android project and `AppDelegate.cs` of iOS.

Then add its namespace and use it like this:

```
  <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                Source="{Binding BirdImage, Mode=OneWay}" HeightRequest="100" />
```

For more information you can check my blog [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/using-ffimageloading-in-xamaring-forms-for-caching-and-optimizing-images-48e381be226b&ved=2ahUKEwjogPynjJzkAhUQH48KHeJ4AVgQFjAEegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw0tc-UYW00n91rxZy4-F3X3)

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out.  I ran across this library in searching for an answer for my issue.  Right now I solved it using UriImageSource and setting CachingEnabled to false.  

I want to move forward a bit, but I will come back around and look to implement FFImageLoading as it seems like a much better solution!

Comment: Sure i am happy to help at all times

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this may have been due to Xamarin caching empty images.  I was finally able to get all of them to display by using this line:

`tmpKB.BirdImage = new UriImageSource { CachingEnabled = false, Uri = new Uri("http://" + Settings.ServerAddress + "/images/bird_examples/" + tmpBird.examplePicture) };`

and setting CachingEnabled to false.